# Simple closure example with Swift

Tags: swift, closures

Im studying swift and i want to simply call closure inside of function. I use following:

```
var task : () -> Void
task = {
    print("Test")
}

func myFunc(times: Int, task: () -> Void){

    task()
}
```

It suppose to print "Test" but it does nothing. What did i miss?

Comment: You never *call* the function – add `myFunc(times: 5, task: task)`

Comment: How are you calling `myFunc`? Remember that the call to `task` in `myFunc` is calling the *argument* `task`, not the global.

Comment: @MartinR yes that was my fault, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way it will work:

```
var task : () -> Void

task = {

    print("Test")
}


func myFunc(times: Int, task: () -> Void){

    task()
}

//call your function this way.
myFunc(times: 2, task: task)  //this will print "Test" in console.
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe Closures in Swift are done this way. Hope it helps.

```
func printTest(){
    print("Test")
}

//task is a variable of type function

var task: () -> Void
task = {
}

task = printTest
printTest()
```

Comment: You have a needless reassignment to `task`. You assign `{ }`, then immediately reassign `printTest`